# How to compile and run Physics2D.NET demos in 64-bit environment

Tags: c#, 2d, physics

In the process of asking my question I have figured out the answers I needed, but am also interested in sharing what I've learned and seeing any other comments people may have as I try to get into 2D physics.

I wanted to play with a 2D physics engine in C#.  I have downloaded Box2dx and Physics2D.Net. The demos for Box2dx ran nicely, but I'm concerned about performance and coding complexity.  So I decided to give Physics2D.Net a try (I can't find much info to compare Box2dx and Physics2d.Net, but I'm reasonably sure Physics2D.Net is simpler to code with based on what I've read, and I have suspicions that it might perform better).  Unfortunately, the demo will not run. I get BadImageFormat exceptions when it try to run the Physics2DDemo sample program on Windows 7 64-bit.

Like I said, I have figured out how to get the demo to run, so I hope you don't mind that I post and accept my own answer, but any other helpful comments related to this topic I will still vote up, and if someone has a better answer (like "try this other download that works better") I could still choose over my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading the source code for SdlDotNet to debug into the source of the BadImageformatException that occurred while loading the font, I discovered it was happening while trying to initialize the font system. My guess as to why this was happening was that there was still some 32-bit DLL running under there somewhere, and all the .NET assemblies were running in a 64-bit process.  So I forced the highest level .NET assemblies to target x86 instead of Any CPU.  To do this from Visual C# 2010 Express, I opened the Build menu, selected "Configuration Manager", selected "x86" as the Active Solution Platform, and made some changes to 3 projects

- Physics2DDemo
- Physics2DDotNet
- Physics2DDotNet.Demo

(I probably didn't need to change all of these, but changing just Physics2DDemo didn't seem to work. It may have been because I needed to re-open the solution and/or rebuild more forcefully, but it eventually worked.)  These are the changes I made to each project:

1. In the platform column, select "<New...>"
2. In the pop-up dialog, select x86 as the New Platform, and select "Any CPU" as the source to copy from.
3. Check the "Build" box.
4. Close the Configuration Manager window and open the Project Settings of this individual project.
5. On the "Build" tab, delete "x86" from the output path, leaving only bin\Debug.

In retrospect, I think I should have checked the "Build" box on every project, which could have reduced some of my problems in getting the project DLL versions to stay in sync with each other.

That did get me past the font problem, but only by a couple lines of code.  Next it was failing when executing the type initializer for SurfaceGl.  It failed on this line:

```
static glLoadIndentityDelegate glLoadIdentity = 
(glLoadIndentityDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
Sdl.SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glLoadIdentity"), typeof(glLoadIndentityDelegate));
```

Apparently SDL_GL_GetProcAddress was returning 0. As it turns out, the code that I had downloaded for SdlDotNet, being somewhat newer than that delivered with Physics2D.Net, was not working with Physics2D.Net.  I replaced the updated DLLs with the original DLL's, and now I am able to compile and run the Physics2D.NET demo!

Of course anyone wanting to incorporate Physics2D.NET into a pure .NET engine, or one that *can* accommodate a 64-bit process will probably want to Build the "AnyCPU" solution target instead of the x86 target.  And it may be worthwhile switching all projects in the x86 solution target to build as x86.

I have noticed that I can now switch the project targets so that Physics2DDemo is the only project building as x86.  The rest of the assemblies, being DLLs, will load into that process as whatever that process chooses to be.  So forcing just that assembly to start a 32-bit process is sufficient.

There may be some steps I neglected to mention here.  I did re-load the solution and force a rebuild a number of times in order for Visual Studio to re-sync with new target locations and versions and such.  But I think all that was because of my switching the SdlDotNet version.  So I hope all that isn't really necessary.

Comment: And BTW, the performance does seem to be *significantly* faster with Physics2D.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a "file not found" after the changes above,

you may also need to add a ..| to the start of the dataDir, so it becomes

```
static readonly string dataDir =
  @"..|..|..|..|data".Replace('|',Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

as in VS2010 you gain an extra layer of directories when you fiddle with platforms and targets...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but I had the same Problem searching for Solutions on Google and I came up here, but realised it simplier than your Solution.
I Realised it by writing:

```
        string dataDir = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf";
        font = new Font(dataDir, 40);
        font.Bold = true;
        font2 = new Font(dataDir, 15);
```

on Lines 97 - 100 on "Demo.cs". Worked for me.